# How to find sum of all of the odd numbers using for loop?

Tags: r

This question for self study. I find it but I stuck when it says return 0 when there is not odd numbers.

Comment: What do you want it to return in that case (all numbers are odd)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R is a vector based language, thus one can avoid the use of loops in many cases with R.

```
oddnumbers <- function(data) {
   #identify the odd numbers data %%2 !=0
   #identify the index of the odd numbers which(...)
   #filter the odds data[...]
   sum(data[(which(data %%2 !=0))])
}

testdata <- trunc(runif(20, 1, 100))
oddnumbers(testdata)
```

Using the `which()` and the built-in vectorized `sum()` function, will perform about 1000x faster than a R loop.

Comment: I don't think you need the `which()`-function here.

Comment: Martin,  good point.  It isn’t needed.

Answer (score 3):

```r
oddnumbers <- function(data) {
  sumodd <- c(0)
  for(i in data) {
    if (i %% 2 != 0) {
      sumodd = sumodd + i
    }
  }
  return (sumodd)
}
```

If you need any explanation, let me know!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked in my example!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).